# Python make image recognition code to loop until something occurs and breaks it

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I have this code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time

#image recognition
def imagesearch(image, precision=0.8):
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img_rgb = np.array(im)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.imread(image, 0)
    template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    if max_val < precision:
        return [-1,-1]
    return max_loc

#continuous image searching on screen
def imagesearch_loop(image, timesample, precision=0.8):
    pos = imagesearch(image, precision)
    while pos[0] == -1:
        print(image+" not found, waiting")
        time.sleep(timesample)
        pos = imagesearch(image, precision)
    return pos

pos = imagesearch_loop("Bonus_Box.png", 0.5)
while not (imagesearch_loop("Bonus_Box.png", 0.5)):
    print("Hello")
    #do things..., after everything finishes and no image found return to while
print("image found ", "x:", pos[0], "y:", pos[1])
```

I am trying to make it loop under a condition. While is not `imagesearch_loop("Bonus_Box.png", 0.5)` I want to make do things but after everything finishes and my image is not anymore found on the screen I want to return to `while not (imagesearch_loop("Bonus_Box.png", 0.5)):` to start searching again.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

you code with other loop, and the easiest way is to just interrupt it with the usual Ctrl-C:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time

#image recognition
def imagesearch(image, precision=0.8):
    im = pyautogui.screenshot()
    img_rgb = np.array(im)
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    template = cv2.imread(image, 0)
    template.shape[::-1]

    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_gray, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
    if max_val < precision:
        return [-1,-1]
    return max_loc

#continuous image searching on screen
def imagesearch_loop(image, timesample, precision=0.8):
    pos = imagesearch(image, precision)
    while pos[0] == -1:
        print(image+" not found, waiting")
        time.sleep(timesample)
        pos = imagesearch(image, precision)
    return pos


try:
    while True:
        pos = imagesearch_loop("Bonus_Box.png", 0.5)
        while not (imagesearch_loop("Bonus_Box.png", 0.5)):
          print("Hello")
          #do things..., after everything finishes and no image found return to while
        print("image found ", "x:", pos[0], "y:", pos[1])
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

Comment: But can I catch Ctrl+C while python is running on the background? The way I was thinking doing it was with `msvcrt.getch()`.